# Safe operating temps - 4790k / 1060GTX

Tags: cooling, temperature, overheating

I've recently got back into the wonderful world of console emulators. they've moved on a lot since my old days of playing SNES games on my pc.

In fact, I've been playing a couple of my favourite PS3 games, and also the new Zelda game. I've noticed it takes my system right to its limit for long periods of time.

I do have one case fan outlet, but no intake or any other fans. Everything else is the basic stock cpu fan, and the ASUS gtx is fully contained so I can't even see the fans.

Anyway, I read somewhere that the inner case temp should never exceed 71C. But mine sits at 70-71C for long times (I've never observed it any higher than 71)

This picture shows the SpeedFan readouts whilst gaming.

Should I be worried about this (ie. to the point where I dont use the emulators) - I have ordered a couple of in-line case fans to help me, but worried about doing lasting damage meanwhile

(NOTE: I am worried about the drives, the GPU and CPU and all other components, not just CPU throttling etc)

[image]

Comment: If your processor is not thermally throttling itself then the temperature is fine.  It is not clear where you got the extremely generic advice that your CPU shouldn't exceed 71 Celsus.  If you want to get cooler temperatures use water cooling and add additional case fans.

Comment: ok thanks. The games run flawlessly so  I dont think the CPU is throttling at all. I've seen it getting to 100% on task manager many times but the game is played fine. But I do smell heat from pc lol and its quite noisey. Glad you say I'll be fine tho, I did think it was ok but wanted to be sure since this hardware cost me a fair whack

Comment: I cant really remember exactly where I got the magic 71C from . But I usually check here and other stack websites the majority of the time. If not I picked it up in some random google foraging lol

Comment: A CPU is going to see 100% usage, you want that to happen, the CPU is designed to be under 100% load.  If your computer shuts down unexpectedly then you have a thermal issue.

Comment: Excellent thank you. Ive had no such problems like shutdowns etc

Comment: It is clear whomever said that general advice didn't have a Haswell processor.

Comment: haha yeah i guess so! They were talking about case temps (it was in a Speedfan specific thread from memory) and they said the PC will mess up if it exceeds 71. It did sound very specific to me, which is what got me worried)

Answer (score 0):

For the CPU:

If it's not throttling itself, then you're fine.  All modern CPU's will handle thermal management reasonably well themselves, up to and including shutting down when they get to critical temperatures likely to cause permanent hardware damage.  Note also that Intel CPU's run notoriously hot (the 70 degree celsius you're talking about is normal operating temperature for a fully loaded fourth generation Core i series CPU).

The actual measurement here is usually taken by a sensor in direct contact with both the silicon itself and the surface of the case that the heatsink is in contact with.

For the GPU:

Similar advice to the CPU.  If it's not showing performance issues, it's probably not an issue.  I've got a laptop with GTX 1060 that regularly runs in the 70 degree celsius range when gaming, and even that doesn't cap out the fans at max speed (based on some rough math I've done, they should cap out when the GPU s at around 80 degrees celsius), so you should be just fine running at 70-71 degrees constantly.

Similar to the CPU, the actual measurement is being taken by a sensor embedded in the silicon itself near the part that is in contact with the heatsink.

For the 'Case Temperature' or 'Motherboard Temperature':

Unless you've got a *really* fancy system that has sensors rigged to measure airflow temperature, these readings are taken by a sensor integrated (similarly to how it's done with the CPU and GPU) into the main chipset (the PCH on Intel systems,, or FCH on AMD, either way it's the modern equivalent of a south bridge).  These usually run in the 30-40 degree celsius range, but it would not surprise me to see them running much hotter if your system is either really compact (like an HTPC system or laptop) or mostly passively cooled (passive cooling translates to a higher ambient air temperature inside the case).

For the disks:

Get a program designed to read the thermal data direct from the drives ([Crystal Disk Info](https://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) is what I use on Windows for this, it also reads the other firmware self-check data, and can be configured to run in the system tray and pop up a warning if the temperature gets too high).

For regular hard drives, you generally want to keep them below 50 degrees celsius (typical long-term temps on idle consumer drives are just short of 40 degrees celsius as a point of reference).  The actual measurement is usually done by an airflow temperature sensor inside the drive itself, but may be handled by sensors on the heads instead (in which case you're essentially measuring the actual temperature of the disks).

For SSD's, the temperature doesn't matter as much, but should ideally be kept within similar ranges to the CPU or GPU at the upper limit.  With an SSD, you usually have an internal sensor similar to how it's done for the CPU and GPU, though some of the nicer ones have one sensor per flash chip and then report an average of all the readings.

In general:

Based on what I've said above, your actual case temperature is probably well below 70 degrees celsius except for right around the individual chips.  You can easily check this yourself simply by putting your hand near the case exhaust fan.  If it's actually 70 degrees celsius inside the case, the airflow from that fan will be too hot to keep your hand in it for more than a few seconds.

Additionally, as a general rule, most consumer electronics (other than batteries) are designed to safely operate at temperatures up to 80-85 degrees celsius.  Until you are dealing with stuff running that hot, you're generally fine.

Finally, slightly off-topic, but your system is going to *produce* the same amount of heat at a given load regardless of what temperature it's running at (for example, a Ryzen 7 1800X will always produce roughly 95W of heat at full load), what actually matters is how efficiently the cooling system can dissipate that heat (which is why big fancy heatsinks result in lower operating temperatures, they're more efficient at moving heat away from the CPU).